# Importing Data into and existing 2013 Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, excel, microsoft-access

I have been using this process for quite a while and while it is a bit cumbersome it has always worked

SharePoint 2016
 Access 2013
 Excel 2013

- Open Access
- Create ne DB
- External Data Connect to SharePoint List
- The Import Excel Spreadsheet into linked list

  I have always been able to import anywhere up to 5,000+ records...  Starting today it dies consistently after 1,000 records every time I try with the following error...

  Cannot Update. Database or Object is read-only

Comment: did you change your list column?

Comment: When you say it dies after 1000 records, do any of those initial 1000 records get imported?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple causes of the “Cannot update. Database or object is read-only” issue.

Check if there are lookup columns or metadata columns in the SharePoint list.

Remove the lookup columns from list and then try to update the list items in Access.

If there is TaxonomyHiddenList linked table in the database, it means the list has (had) the metadata columns.
Re-create the list without the metadata columns.

Refer to the following article:

["Cannot update. Database or object is read-only" error in linked SharePoint list in Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3200680/-cannot-update--database-or-object-is-read-only-error-in-linked-sharep)